# Cual es la mejor forma de validar un TextBox XAML

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

Tengo una aplicación UWP que utiliza varios `TextBox` para recoger información del usuario:

```
<Grid>
    <TextBox Text="{Binding Codigo}"></TextBox>
    <TextBox Text="{Binding Producto}"></TextBox>
    <TextBox Text="{Binding Cantidad}"></TextBox>
</Grid>
```

Mi pregunta, ¿cuál es la mejor forma de validar que el usuario no ingrese datos incorrectos, es decir, hacer que los `TextBox` solo permitan ingresar números o algún tipo de mascara de caracteres?

Se debe hacer desde código o se puede hacer desde XAML

Comment: Estas implementado el patron MVVM ? si es asi con algun framework en concreto?

Comment: Si estoy implementando MVVM pero no utilizo un framework en concreto

Comment: Espero no tengas afán, es fin de semana y no ando muy disponible ;)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Actualmente `UWP` no incorpora ningún framework de validación, sin embargo la comunidad de C# es pujante y en GitHub ya hay una alternativa muy interesante que vale la pena revisar: [**ValidatableBase**](https://github.com/scionwest/ValidatableBase) para usarlo debes descargar el código de GitHub y compilar la librería para luego añadirla a la solución.

### El modelo

lo que debes hacer es crear un modelo que herede de `ValidatableBase`, como seguramente estás usando `BindableBase` te convendría usar algo como este

```
using Sullinger.ValidatableBase.Models;
public class User
{
    BindableBase binder;
    private string name;
    public string Name
    {
        get { return name; }
        set { binder.SetProperty(ref name, value); }
    }
    private string email;
    public string Email
    {
        get { return email; }
        set { binder.SetProperty(ref email, value); }
    }
    public User()
    {
        binder = new BindableBase();
        email = name = string.Empty;            
    }
}
```

### El viewModel

Para disparar la validación puedes hacerlo de muchas formas pero una forma es con un botón en cuyo caso conviene tener un ViewModel así.

```
public class MainPageVM : BindableBase, ICommand
{
    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;
    public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        return true;
    }
    public void Execute(object parameter)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
    private User usuario;
    public User Usuario
    {
        get { return usuario; }
        set { SetProperty(ref usuario, value); }
    }
    private string errores;
    public string Errores
    {
        get { return errores; }
        set
        { SetProperty(ref errores, value); }
    }
    public MainPageVM()
    {
        errores = string.Empty;
        usuario = new User();
    }        
}
```

### XAML y binding

El `XAML` con el que debes bindear es como este

```
<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Center">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <TextBlock Text="Nombre: "/>
            <TextBox Text="{Binding Usuario.Name, Mode=TwoWay}" />
        </StackPanel>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <TextBlock Text="Email: "/>
            <TextBox Text="{Binding Usuario.Email, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
        </StackPanel>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <TextBlock Text="Errores :"/>
            <TextBlock Width="400" Height="100" Text="{Binding Errores}" />
        </StackPanel>
        <Button HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Command="{Binding}">
            Validar
        </Button>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

### Agregando atributos de validación a las propiedades del modelo

Una vez tienes todo listo entonces decoras el modelo con atributos de validación, he incluido en el ejemplo validación de campo requerido y validación de que el valor email sea en efecto un correo electrónico, haciendo uso de una validación personalizada.

```
using System.ComponentModel;

namespace App5.Models
{
    using Sullinger.ValidatableBase.Models;
    using Sullinger.ValidatableBase.Models.ValidationRules;
    using System.Reflection;
    using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
    public class User : ValidatableBase
    {
        BindableBase binder;

        private string name;

        [ValidateObjectHasValue(FailureMessage = "El nombre no se puede dejar en blanco",
                                 ValidationMessageType = typeof(ValidationErrorMessage))]
        public string Name
        {
            get { return name; }
            set { binder.SetProperty(ref name, value); }
        }

        private string email;

        [ValidateWithCustomHandler( DelegateName = "IsValidEmail",
                                    FailureMessage = "Esto no parece un correo electrónico",
                                    ValidationMessageType = typeof(ValidationWarningMessage))]
        [ValidateObjectHasValue(FailureMessage = "El email no se puede dejar en blanco",
                         ValidationMessageType = typeof(ValidationErrorMessage))]
        public string Email
        {
            get { return email; }
            set { binder.SetProperty(ref email, value); }
        }

        public User()
        {
            binder = new BindableBase();
            email = name = string.Empty;
        }

        [ValidationCustomHandlerDelegate(DelegateName = "IsValidEmail")]
        private IValidationMessage IsValidEmail(IValidationMessage failureMessage, PropertyInfo property)
        {
            const string regExp = @"\A(?:[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*@(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\.)+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?)\Z";

            return Regex.IsMatch(this.Email, regExp, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)
                ? null
                : failureMessage;
        }
    }
}
```

### Procesando los errores en el ViewModel

Finalmente en el Viewmodel implementar el método `Execute` para que te ponga en `Errores` todos los errores de todas las propiedades del modelo, quedando así

```
    public void Execute(object parameter)
    {
        Errores = string.Empty;
        Usuario.ValidateAll();

        if (Usuario.HasValidationMessages())
        {
            var propiedades = Usuario.GetValidationMessages();

            foreach (var propiedad in propiedades)
            {
                foreach (var error in propiedad.Value)
                {
                    Errores += $"{propiedad.Key}: {error.Message}\n";
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Ya con eso te funcionará.

> De plano el tema no es difícil, pero no es un tema que se pueda explicar de manera muy corta porque hay muchas cosas que se requieren. En esta respuesta tienes el resumen de todo, pero adivino que puedes quedar bastante perdido en algunas partes por lo que he escrito un artículo muy detallado en mi blog que te guiará paso a paso en caso de que requieras.

### [UWP - Cómo implementar validación de campos en Universal Apps](https://juank.io/uwp-como-implementar-validacion-campos-universal-apps/)

Answer (score 0):

Podrias hacer uso de **DataAnnotations**, agregando la referencia a `System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations`

Básicamente, en tu `ViewModel` defines el atributo sobre la propiedad que bindeas al control en la view:

```
public class xxViewModel : ViewModelBase {

    //resto propiedades

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Debe ingresar una cantidad")] 
    public int Cantidad {get;set;}

}
```

Para mas detalle recomiendo este articulo
[Validation in MVVM using Data Annotations](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/Validation-in-MVVM-using-12dafef3),
está muy completo

---

Por tratarse de una aplicacion UWP quizas la libreria de DataAnnotations no te deje referenciarla, pero siguendo el mismo camino hay alternativa con:

- [WinRTXamlValidation](https://github.com/krishna-nadiminti/WinRTXamlValidation)

Básicamente es lo mismo, defines atributos de validación en las propiedades del `ViewModel`, solo que usarias una implementación adecuada a WinRT.